# Failed to check for map support: write failed: No space left on device

Tags: monerod, whonix

Hi complete noob here but still want to run a monero node:

I completed the Qubes Whonix Isolation guide for a monero node.

I created a wallet in wallet-ws then. Shutdown.
Then I opened monerod-ws and ran:
monerod --log-level 4
in terminal and got some errors:

```
T BlockchainLMDB::open
W Failed to check for Nmap support: write failed: No space left on device
E Error opening database: Failed to check for map support: write failed: No space left on device.
E Exception in main! Failed to initialize core.
```

Before this however I used to get the
Failed to bind IPv4 to 0.0.0.0 etc error.
But this time I ran  monerod  and got this new error somehow it changed smh.

In the qubes manager section I set the Private storage max to 95000MiB
The System storage is at 10240 MiB and gray out so I can't change that.

But I also remember I had my qubes to dynamically increase in size as I use them so Idk why it's saying now that disk is full but yesterday it was a different error.
How do I increase the size of the device?

And where can I find list of commands to troubleshoot daemon.

Like:
How to know if daemon is sync blocks and how many.
How to know if daemon is connected to tor.
Am I supposed to change the ip of the daemon to my own ip as in the ip of the monerod-ws vm?

I tried the --help section but I am super noob.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are running monerod in prunning mode, you'll need more than "95000MiB".

Storage seems full. You can check with `df -h` inside daemon workstation.

By default, Qubes workstations can't communicate between them. You can check [this resource](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/cli_wallet_daemon_isolation_qubes_whonix.html) for one possible configuration

Comment: Question

I set private storage max size to 13448 MiB,(120gb) more than enough.

However, when I run df -h in the terminal I get:
Size Used. Avail.
Dev/xvdb 13GB. 13GB. 0

Why does this block have a limit when I set the max limit to 120GB.

(My system storage max size is 10240MiB.)

My qube is on the dynamically change size if that even matters.

Comment: it should increase as needed. 13 000 MiB is about 13 GB not 120